# Could an octopus ride a bicycle?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, interspecies-relations

I'm imagining a scenario where there is a conflict between humans and intelligent octopuses. The humans' main mode of transport is the bicycle.

The octopuses decide to stage a night raid whereby they will steal the                 humans' bicycles and dispose of them at the bottom of the sea. The problem is that they must transport the bikes from land to the coast. Dragging these would make a noise so the octopus plan to ride the bikes.

**Question**

Assuming that the intelligent octopuses are of a size to reach the pedals and the handlebars, could an octopus actually ride a bicycle - even in theory? What aspects of biology could prevent it.

**Notes**

Assume that the octopuses can survive out of water for the time required. (real-life octopuses do sometimes travel short distances on land)

Assume that the octopuses have worked out a way to mount the bikes but they can't support their full body weight clear of the ground on their tentacles for any length of time - hence needing to use the saddle.

Comment: You mean civilised Octopuses right? Cephalopods are scary intelligent.

Comment: @Ash - You could put it that way. They can certainly communicate as well as we can, form complex plans, and work as a team. I don't think real ones can do all of that.

Comment: My gut says this should be possible, but the fact that I've never seen a clip of an octopus riding a bike makes me second-guess myself, because that is obviously something that should exist in this day and age.

Comment: Can those octopuses stand on their tentacles, when out of the water?

Comment: @Alexander - They can't support their entire weight clear of the ground for any great length of time. That's why they need to use the saddle once in motion.

Comment: So the crucial point is how long is "great length of time". If their tentacles are nearly as strong and supporting as human legs, they can do it. If not, how can they get the bicycle going?

Comment: @Alexander -  Well that's part of my question. That's why I used the biology tag and reality-check. I'm hoping someone knows this kind of thing.

Comment: @chasly from UK For real life octopuses, the answer is "No" - their tentacles are not strong enough to support them on shore. But your octopuses may be different, strong ones, so the answer would become "Yes".

Comment: It depends on how your octopusses are set up. If they can walk even for a short while and can balance themselves they can use a bicycle, although it would be easier if their tentacles are around 23kg total (average weight of 2 legs of a 70kg male). Most of the weight of a cycling person is simply supported by the saddle, which is why cycling is so easy compared to walking (not forgetting how important a flat solid road is). So with the assumptions of weight, tentacle length and ability to walk for a short while down pat it should be possible.

Comment: Can two octopuses stand on either side of the bike and give it a big shove to get a third one riding it a good start?

Comment: This reminds me of an old adage: "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"  Answer: "He would chuck all the wood that a woodchuck could chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood."  Short answer: if you want them too.  The extra "legs" might even give them a number of advantages (speed, sharp turns, able to slap someone on the way by more easily...).

Comment: Octopus#1: "this pedalling is tedious." Octopus#2: "I think you should grip the handles with the other 6 tentacles..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Octopuses are fairly strong for their size; so, being physically able to ride a bike should not be an obstacle.  Practically speaking, probably not so much.

Even humans that have never ridden a bike before generally can not do it without falling over repeatedly and making a bunch of noise.  So assuming bike riding is not a thing octopuses already teach their young, then a random night raid like this would fail hilariously.

To further complicate the matter, octopuses have decentralized motor control over their tentacles.  This means that their brain can give a limb a general idea of what that limb should do, but then the tentacle decides how to do it.  This would probably make activities that require each part of the octopus's body to work in tandem for things like riding a bike pretty difficult compared to an animal with a centralized control system.

Comment: +1 for the need to learn to ride a bike.

Comment: I'm now imagining that our octopus army has somehow managed to acquire a single bicycle, and are all taking turns learning how to ride it in preparation for the big raid.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's anything to prevent an octopus from riding a bicycle with the possible exception of force exertion, I'm not sure that an octopus can get enough down force from it's tentacles to move the peddles. In short they may not be strong enough but otherwise they're biomechanically adaptable enough for the task.

As a note any octopus big enough and strong enough to ride a bicycle can probably *carry* it completely off the ground more easily than they can ride it.

Comment: With the right gearing, the force required to move the pedals can be quite small. They might not do well on a single-speed bike, but any bike that's built to climb hills may work.

Comment: Pedals need not be pushed down. You can also pull them up on the upturn.

Comment: @NuclearWang Any bike will possibly work, I'm just not sure how strong an octopus is and how much force it needs.